# XSLT 2.0 build element dynamically

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to write an xslt to transform the following XML:

```
<instruments>
<instrument>1111-A01</instrument>
<instrument>1111-A02</instrument>
<instrument>2222-A03</instrument>
<instrument>2222-A04</instrument>
</instruments>
```

to the following XML:

```
<references>
<reference>
    <id_celex>1111</id_celex>
    <article>A01</article>
    <article>A02</article>
</reference>
<reference>
    <id_celex>2222</id_celex>
    <article>A03</article>
    <article>A04</article>
</reference>
</references>
```

So I need to split each instrument at the '-' to get **id_celex** and **article**.
Then for each unique **id_celex** I need to create a reference with the **id_celex** and its **article** s.

I started xslt yesterday and I'm already stuck :p

Thank you in advance!

I have a few lines but as it's not working I'm not sure if it's useful to show it...

Comment: If your XSLT includes the **xsl:for-each-group** instruction, then yes, it would be useful to show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="instruments">
    <references>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="instrument" group-by="substring-before(text(),'-')">
        <reference>
          <id_celex>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          </id_celex>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <article>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),'-')"/>
            </article>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </reference>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </references>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Whaw! Thank you very much. I didn't know the for-each-group function. I will try to understand you code now :)